# sqlite sql syntax error near '('

Tags: android, sqlite

> sqlite sql syntax error near '('

```
<code>
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase arg0) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("create table IF NOT EXISTS " + tableName + "(" );
    sb.append(" eng TEXT primary key,");
    sb.append(" gra TEXT not null,");
    sb.append(" memo TEXT null,");
    sb.append(" fsen TEXT null,");
    sb.append(" ox INTEGER not null DEFAULT 0,");
    sb.append(" oxSeq TEXT null,");
    sb.append(" timeCreate TEXT not null DEFAULT datetime('now', 'localtime'),");
    sb.append(" timeLast TEXT not null DEFAULT datetime('now', 'localtime') )");
    arg0.execSQL(sb.toString());
    Log.w(" -- Result -- ", tableName + " is created.");
    }

    ////Error message is like following...

    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "(": 
    syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: 
    create table IF NOT EXISTS userDic( 
    eng TEXT primary key, 
    kor TEXT not null, 
    memo TEXT null, 
    fsen TEXT null, 
    ox INTEGER not null DEFAULT 0, 
    oxSeq TEXT null, 
    timeCreate TEXT not null DEFAULT datetime('now', 'localtime'), 
    timeLast TEXT not null DEFAULT datetime('now', 'localtime') ) 
</code>
```

I don't know why the error is occurred...
I don't know why the error is occurred...
I don't know why the error is occurred...
I don't know why the error is occurred...
I don't know why the error is occurred...
I don't know why the error is occurred...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I found the answer with others' idea.

Problem is `DEFAULT`

I need to change the part

```
DEFAULT datetime('now', 'localtime')
```

to

```
DEFAULT(datetime('now', 'localtime'))
```

`()` is needed. Now it's working.

Answer (score 2):

To use a default *value*, replace `datetime('now', 'localtime')` with e.g. `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. Note that it won't be localtime but UTC zulu time.

To use an expression as a default, it needs to be in `()` parentheses, e.g. `DEFAULT(datetime('now', 'localtime'))`.

https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html

Comment: I see... so... I need to change the part "DEFAULT datetime('now', 'localtime')"  as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP...

Answer (score -1):

`tableName` needs to be surrounded in single quotes:

corrected:

```
 sb.append("create table IF NOT EXISTS '" + tableName + "' (" );
```

Comment: @FrankN.Stein oh am I wrong? Just went and looked it up in my project and am using single quotes around the table name, then again i am not using `.execSQL`

Comment: Try removing them, it will work as well (if the table name is a single word). OR maybe your table name contains spaces (but I use `[` and `]` in that case).